# Interrupt 10h not working

Tags: assembly, architecture, x86, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am getting segmentation fault in the program below.
This is for set the cursor on the top-left of the screen. But why i am getting segmentation fault on this program? 
Thanks for the replies.

```
section .text
global main
main:
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 1
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    int 10h
```

I think that the problem is the protected mode that i am working. This is an 16-bit instruction and i am trying this in a 32-bit machine! Am i correct?

I am running this program in a Linux Ubuntu distribution 32-bits. THe processor is AMD C-60.

Comment: I believe you are correct, but you might want to augment your question with some more information about your environment.

Comment: Sorry, i set more information about my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIOS interrupts are 16-bit code. Your OS has put the CPU in 32-bit protected mode. The hardware will allow a switch back to 16-bit real mode (there are hoops to jump through) but the OS won't allow it. Wouldn't be very "protected" if it did. It is "protected" from US, my friend!

I think what you probably want to look into is "vt100" terminal emulation. By rights, a "robust" program would consult the "termcaps" file to make sure vt100 emulation is available before attempting to use it. My experience is that it's "usually" available on a "desktop Linux" box, so I just ASSume it's there. Worst that can happen (I think) is garbage on the screen if we ASSume wrong.

This example doesn't do exactly what you want. It saves the current cursor position (lord knows where), moves the cursor to a new position, prints a message, and goes back to the original cursor position. You'll need to look up the "home cursor" command ("ESC [h"? lookitup). Just write it to stdout, same as "hello world". You can get colors and stuff, too.

```
; nasm -f elf32 mygem.asm
; ld -o mygem mygem.o -melf_i386

global _start

section .data
savecursor db 1Bh, '[s'
.len equ $ - savecursor

unsavecursor db 1Bh, '[u'
.len equ $ - unsavecursor

getcursor db 1Bh, '[6n'
.len equ $ - getcursor

setcursor db 1Bh, '[10;20H'
.len equ $ - setcursor

msg db "Hello, new cursor position!"
.len equ $ - msg

section .text
_start:

mov ecx, savecursor
mov edx, savecursor.len
call write_stdout


mov ecx, setcursor
mov edx, setcursor.len
call write_stdout

mov ecx, msg
mov edx, msg.len
call write_stdout

mov ecx, unsavecursor
mov edx, unsavecursor.len
call write_stdout

exit:
mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
int 80h

;------------------------
write_stdout:    
push eax
push ebx
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
int 80h
pop ebx
pop eax
ret
;---------------------
```

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use the "ncurses" library. They make me say that. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
That is a manner to switch from protected mode to real mode [see this](http://www.sudleyplace.com/pmtorm.html). I don't test this, but i will try...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
org 100h
section .text
global main
main:
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 1
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    int 10h
```

Please read [this](http://www.oocities.org/codeteacher/x86asm/asml1009.html):

> This org 100h actually tells assembly that our program will begin at
>   offset 100h. Why is this necessary? It is because all running programs
>   have Process Control Block (PCB) with it. It's sort of thing for
>   operating system to manage stuffs, So, it's better for us not to
>   interfere with that unless you're doing advanced stuff. After that, we
>   have a jump, right? Then after that jump, you put all your data in,
>   right? That's how we cope with this chaos. The unconditional jump
>   ensures the space for data so that it does not interfere with code.
>   and vice versa. It is usually the case when the code interferes with
>   data, it will cause hangups, blue screen of death and so on, --again
>   -- UNLESS you are an assembly guru that knows what you're doing (like doing some self-modification code stuff and similar arcane tricks).

---

For linux you should work only with system calls [this is a well documented tutorial](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/), you put in `eax` the number of the [sys call](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) and jump to it/ switch into kernel mode with `int 80h`:

```
section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
    helloLen:  equ $-hello             ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string
                                       ; (I'll explain soon)

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
    mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
    mov ecx,hello        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
    mov edx,helloLen     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
                         ;  mov edx,[helloLen] to get it's actual value
    int 80h              ; Call the kernel

    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h
```

Comment: This is not working... Sorry, i didn't post my OS. But i am working on Linux and this instruction is for .COM files for Windows. I get the idea! But i am curious because this instruction is not working! The NASM don't see this like an instruction... what i am doing wrong?

Comment: ohhh that is for windows indeed. what compiler are you using? nasm? put all the sequence you are following... moreover I don't think 10h works on linux, you need to create system call with int 80h. you should follow the right tutorials. good luck.

Comment: Yes, i am using nasm... I copy and paste your code!
but what you think about this?
"7.9.7 16−bit code and ELF
The ELF32 specification doesn’t provide relocations for 8− and 16−bit values, but the GNU ld linker adds
these as an extension. NASM can generate GNU−compatible relocations, to allow 16−bit code to be linked as
ELF using GNU ld. If NASM is used with the −w+gnu−elf−extensions option, a warning is issued
when one of these relocations is generated."

The idea is that i use an instruction of 16 bit, right?

Comment: There is a system call: ioctl.
Using this i can do the same. But this means that i can't access the BIOS with Linux Kernel? If i switch to Kernel mode?

Comment: Once a kernel switches to protected mode, access to the BIOS isn't normally possible, except via a dos like emulator, such as DOSBOX or a virtual pc setup with DOS. I don't know what options there are for Linux. For Windows, you could try to buy an old 16 bit tool set like Visual C++ 1.52 (includes masm) or older (VC 4.x includes 1.52 toolset). If you just want assembly, then masm 6.11 (actual name is ml.exe) will do.

Comment: @rcgldr the nasm will happily assemble 16b code, even into DOS ".com" file (bin output mode), it's not problem of NASM per se (although it will protest a bit when target is 32/64b ELF). It's just pointless to run such ".com" under linux. So nasm is still possible choice, even for 16b environment. But you need that 16b environment (IMHO dosbox should work for small things ...and nobody sane will do anything medium/large for DOS, right? Especially when they have linux available.)

Comment: @Ped7g - I don't know about running 16 bit dos apps with Linux. 32 bit versions of windows support 16 bit dos apps (including a dos extender), but not 64 bit versions of windows. The alternative is to use a virtual pc, in which case you can install MSDOS, with expanded and extended memory support. Watcom C++ 10.0 includes a 32 bit flat model that runs under DOS / Win 3.11 winmem32 bit mode. I mostly use DOSBOX / Virtual PC / 16 bit apps for old games or to help people trying to program in 16 bit real mode.

Comment: @rcgldr yeah, I somehow managed to not deliver the message... there's also DOS executable (16b from 2005 and 32b from 2009) of nasm, and also windows one. Although I would personally do crosscompiling from linux, but that's because I already have linux as desktop OS. I just wanted to point out, that whatever common x86 environment you set up, nasm probably exists for it (may be not the latest one).

Comment: @Ped7g - true, but Masm (ML.EXE) 6.11 includes some features not found in other assemblers, like the dot directives such as .if .else .endif .while, ...  . Take a look at [msdn masm reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx) .