# Nasm print string bug

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Here is my bios nasm "Hello world" program. What am I doing wrong with my for loop ? I believe here is the bug "    mov al,[msg + esi] " but I'm not familiarized with nasm only with the old tasm .. so I can't figure out how it should be.

Btw , shouldn't I load the data segment somewhere like in tasm ?

```
section .data

msg: db "Welcome to NexusOS :)"
len: equ $ - msg


section .text


global main

main:

    mov ah,0x0E ; BIOS print funciton
    mov esi,0

    for:

        mov al,[msg + esi]
        int 0x10

        inc esi
        cmp esi,len
        jl for

    ret
```

Edit , output : "S  ≡S  ≡S  ≡S  ≡S  ≡S"

Comment: What's wrong with the program? Do you get an assembly error? Does it assemble but create incorrect output?

Comment: It assembles but it creates incorrect output yes

Comment: And what would that output be?

Comment: Strange output, S ≡S ≡S ≡S ≡S ≡S

Comment: TASM and NASM only differ in **syntax**. Everything you do in TASM you should do in NASM as well (like setting the ES register).

Comment: Could you please show me how ? I mean where should I set it ?

Comment: BTW `int 10h` function `0Eh` is supposed to take the active display page in `bh`. You can ascertain this with `int 10h` function `0Fh`.

Comment: @Weather Vane I know that but it works like this also if in al I load a single character like "a" it prints it out correctly

Comment: Does it help if you put a line `org 0x100` just behind the `section .text`? Please show the full command line(s) to produce the executable program. Does the program run in a MS-DOS environment and if yes: which?

Comment: @rkhb I don't think that's the issue because the program looks like running fine except not outputting the desired values.

Comment: You should set if before printing. How do you do it in TASM? Well, same for NASM (except syntax).

Comment: @lurker why `es`? Using `esi` to read memory will default to using `ds:esi`. Alessandro so why don't you set `ds` (as you said you have done previously), or will `ds` already be set before `main` executes?

Comment: @WeatherVane oops my bad, I meant `ds`. It's not clear whether it's being preset before `main` is called.

Comment: @Weather Vane  , the problem is that I don't know how to set ds ( like I do in tasm ) "mov ax,data
 mov ds,ax' would be in tasm

Comment: Then I suggest you find a working code example from the NASM documentation.

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088845/interrupt-10h-not-working).

Comment: Are you sure the linker and the program loader (of "NexusOS") agree on the location of the program in memory?